# Change fontsize in holoviews or hvplot

Tags: python, holoviews, hvplot, holoviz

How do I change fontsizes using holoviews or hvplot?

Here's a simple example of the plot I have:

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import holoviews as hv
import hvplot.pandas
hv.extension('bokeh', logo=False)

# create sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': np.random.normal(size=30),
    'col2': np.random.normal(size=30),
})

# plot data with holoviews
my_plot = hv.Scatter(df, label='Scattering around')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** You can change fontsizes by **using .opts(fontsize={})** on your plot, like so:

```
# change fontsizes for different parts of plot
my_plot.opts(fontsize={
    'title': 15, 
    'labels': 14, 
    'xticks': 10, 
    'yticks': 10,
})
```

**2)** With **version >= 1.13 of holoviews** you can **scale all the fonts** all at once and make legend, title, xticks larger with **.opts(fontscale=1.5)**:

```
# make fonts all at once larger for your plot by the same scale
# here I've chosen fontscale=2, which makes all fonts 200% larger
my_plot.opts(fontscale=2)
```

**3)** If you would like to **scale your fonts** and you have a bokeh backend for your holoviews plot, you can do:

```
# scale fontsizes with 200%
my_plot.opts(fontsize={
    'title': '200%',
    'labels': '200%', 
    'ticks': '200%', 
})
```

More info on all the possible parts of which you can change the fontsize can be found here:
 http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Customizing_Plots.html#Font-sizes

Comment: How does this work with hvplot? For example, neither,
df.hvplot.labels(x='A',y='B',text='C',size=4)
nor
df.hvplot.labels(x='A',y='B',text='C',fontsize={'labels':4})
seems to have any effect on the labels size.