# Fontsize of data labels in Holoview

Tags: python, holoviews

Does anybody know how to change the font size of the data labels in the holoview?
I followed this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070661/change-fontsize-in-holoviews-or-hvplot), but only changes the font size of axes labels, title, and ticks.
Here is my code:

```
p=hv.Bars(data_small,kdims=['MONTH'], vdims=['count'])
labels = hv.Labels(data=data_small, kdims=['MONTH', 'y_count'], vdims=['count'])
labels.opts(fontscale=1)
p*labels
```

Here is the picture of what I'm getting. I want to make numbers [258, 232, 277,255...] smaller.

[image: Holoview chart]

Comment: It's hard to answer definitively without a reproducible example, but you could try `.opts(label_text_font_size='12pt')`